# What does Xamarin iOS compile down to?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I know this question has sort of been asked, but the answer I'm looking for has never been addressed.

I'm aware that Xamarin compiles down to IL, which then gets turned into a native binary, but I have a more specific question that relates to how memory gets managed.

My question has to do with memory management in the native binary, when compiling C# to Android, you have a handle to the object for system resources in both .NET and in native Java, and in some cases (like bitmaps), you need to clean up both (clean up .NET handles for objects, and also the native object in Java itself), this is the case because Java and C# are both garbage collected languages. As far as Swift goes, garbage collection isn't something that happens, it's all reference counting, so memory management is much less of a concern, and to add to this, my co-worker who built the iOS side of our Xamarin app never had memory issues, while I had quite a few in the Android app.

From this I've derived that at some level the memory must get handled differently in Xamarin Android vs. Xamarin iOS, but I don't know for sure because I don't know how iOS apps get compiled, what would answer this question is knowing what language Xamarin iOS compiles down to, so my question is, does Xamarin iOS compile down to Objective-C, Swift, or something else? I'd like to have a better idea of what's going on so I know how to handle memory in iOS apps.

Having said all of that, it's entirely possible that our iOS app didn't have any memory leaks because my co-worker just know better than I did when writing it, and I could just be incompetent and be drawing the wrong conclusions, if this is the case, please feel free to let me know.

If I've worded this question weird let me know and I'll attempt to clarify what I mean.

Comment: This may have changed since I read it way back, but because Apple didn't initially allow virtual machines on iOS, Xamarin for iOS AOT-compiled the IL directly to native code.  It seems unlikely to me that it added a C-like language as an intermediate step.  Probably just used a modified version of the VM's JIT code to go straight from IL to native binary.  I think the native code for the garbage collector was built into the binary.

Comment: That's similar to what I've read as well, so it seems like that's the case...so then does garbage collection happen at runtime or is it reference counting for iOS?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, garbage collection happens at runtime.

Comment: I should add that reference counting is a service provided by the Objective-C or Swift runtime, and `NSObject`s are reference counted.  So while the .NET objects you create in your C# code will be garbage-collected, some will wrap `NSObject`s that are reference counted.  You should be able to trust the Xamarin guys to ensure that all `NSObject`s wrapped by Xamarin classes will be properly managed, with the caveat that you should probably explicitly `Dispose()` .NET objects that wrap `NSObject`s when you're done with them so they get disposed immediately rather than when the GC gets to them.

Comment: That pretty well answers my question then I think, thanks!